# Datatables - no search or filter feature

Tags: php, datatables

I recently got this to work on another application I am working on and thought I'd apply it to an existing project, but it's not working for the second thing. I feel like I'm missing some js file or something but I've tried everything I can find. I tried to get it to work on a simple page test and it seems to show the CSS, but not the search or filtering.

Here is my page:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').DataTable( {

        } );
    });
</script>

<table id="myTable" class="display table" width="80%">
    <tr>
        <th>stuff</th><th>things</th><th>hi</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gofgdjk</td><td>sdf</td><td>tedsdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gofgdjk</td><td>sdf</td><td>tedsdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gofgdjk</td><td>sdf</td><td>tedsdf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, I do remember reading that originally but I must have forgotten when quickly doing this page.

Comment: I added this to my actual project with wordpress and the filter and search are now there but they don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Datatables website states in the usage page you need thead and tbody tags for it to initialize

```
<table id="myTable" class="display table" width="80%">
       <thead> <tr>
            <th>stuff</th><th>things</th><th>hi</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>gofgdjk</td><td>sdf</td><td>tedsdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>gofgdjk</td><td>sdf</td><td>tedsdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gofgdjk</td><td>sdf</td><td>tedsdf</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got that part but adding it to my actual project on wordpress it wont allow me to filter or use the search. (though it is there now)

Comment: You need to include the jquery CDN / script link ABOVE the Datatables script inclusions in your headers, try moving stuff around order wise and see if any errors appear in developer console

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it didnt change anything. I have the table in a foreach selecting from a DB. would that cause it not to work?

Comment: Does anyone know exactly which CND i need for the table and the sort/search to work? I have just the 2 things from datatables.net and jquery and the search won't work.

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: Strange it works for my basic page and not my project page